# Android - большой ответ на POST запрос

Tags: android, http

Пишу приложение для Android и в настоящий момент работаю над отправкой POST запросов на сервер и обработкой принимаемой информации. Сначала всё шло очень хорошо, пока возвращаемые данные не стали очень объёмными. В общем, возвращается информация не полностью, а только часть. С помощью CURL проверил запрос, как оказалось, данных должно быть на много больше. Ручное увеличение буфера ни к чему не привело, количество выводимых символов остался прежним (вот код - `Reader in = new BufferedReader(_ISR,999999);`). Как вывести весь код запроса? Как увеличить буфер или поток или ещё что-то??? Вот текущий код:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite");
    try {
        //Добавляем свои данные
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", "search"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fio", _fio));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", _city));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", _company));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", _email));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStreamReader _ISR = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            Reader in = new BufferedReader(_ISR);
            int ch;
            int _col = 0;
            while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
                buffer.append((char)ch);
                _col++;
            }
        in.close(); 
        Log.i("MyApp", "_Return col - "+_col+" str - "+buffer);
```

Comment: может gzip поможет? Это весьма хорошо сжимает данные. На сервере надо сделать поддержку этого. Попробуйте:  
       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

Comment: Что мешает читать буфера в цикле?

Comment: и еще, надеюсь вы это делаете в фоновом потоке, потому что в UI-потоке может все повиснуть и данные не все будут получены

Comment: Сервером не я занимаюсь.
В смысле "читать буфер в цикле"? У меня разве не в цикле? Подскажите если не так! Если вы про считывание строк, то да, пробовал , считывается только первая строка.
Да, в фоновом потоке конечно.

Comment: В цикле, это значит читаете буфер, обрабатываете данные, читаете следующий буфер и т.д. пока есть данные. 

Сколько и как читать можно узнать из заголовка http.

Comment: Всё считывалось правильно, в буфер всё не помещалось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если выводите полученные данные через logcat то нужно учитывать что его буфер тоже не резиновый.

// Prints the size of the specified log buffer and exits.

```
adb logcat -g
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!! Буфер LogCat и вправду оказался "нерезиновым"! )))